# Unable to launch Spyder IDE Linux. Error: PyQt5 5.9+ is required (found None)

Tags: python, linux, pyqt5, spyder

I am running Spyder IDE on Red Hat Linux. I installed Spyder in a virtual environment as outlined https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html and this was running without a problem. I now following message when I launch

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/<my_name>/spyder-env/bin/spyder", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/<my_name>/spyder-env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 248, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/home/<my_name>/spyder-env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 41, in <module>
    requirements.check_qt()
  File "/home/<my_name>/spyder-env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/requirements.py", line 54, in check_qt
    show_warning("Please check Spyder installation requirements:\n"
  File "/home/<my_name>/spyder-env/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/requirements.py", line 32, in show_warning
    raise RuntimeError(message)
RuntimeError: Please check Spyder installation requirements:
PyQt5 5.9+ is required (found None).
```

Here are a list of packages and versions I have installed, with PyQT5

```
python3 -m pip list
Package                       Version
----------------------------- -------------------
absl-py                       1.0.0
alabaster                     0.7.12
arrow                         1.2.2
astroid                       2.11.3
asttokens                     2.0.5
astunparse                    1.6.3
atomicwrites                  1.4.0
attrs                         21.4.0
autopep8                      1.6.0
Babel                         2.10.1
backcall                      0.2.0
beautifulsoup4                4.11.1
binaryornot                   0.4.4
black                         22.3.0
bleach                        5.0.0
cachetools                    5.0.0
certifi                       2021.10.8
cffi                          1.15.0
chardet                       4.0.0
charset-normalizer            2.0.12
click                         8.1.3
cloudpickle                   2.0.0
cookiecutter                  1.7.3
cryptography                  37.0.1
cycler                        0.11.0
deap                          1.3.1
debugpy                       1.6.0
decorator                     5.1.1
defusedxml                    0.7.1
Deprecated                    1.2.13
diff-match-patch              20200713
dill                          0.3.4
docutils                      0.17.1
entrypoints                   0.4
executing                     0.8.3
fastjsonschema                2.15.3
flake8                        4.0.1
flatbuffers                   2.0
fonttools                     4.33.3
gast                          0.5.3
google-auth                   2.6.6
google-auth-oauthlib          0.4.6
google-pasta                  0.2.0
grpcio                        1.44.0
h5py                          3.6.0
idna                          3.3
imagesize                     1.3.0
imbalanced-learn              0.9.0
imblearn                      0.0
importlib-metadata            4.11.3
inflection                    0.5.1
intervaltree                  3.1.0
ipykernel                     6.13.0
ipython                       7.32.0
ipython-genutils              0.2.0
isort                         5.10.1
jedi                          0.18.1
jeepney                       0.8.0
jellyfish                     0.9.0
Jinja2                        3.0.3
jinja2-time                   0.2.0
joblib                        1.1.0
jsonschema                    4.4.0
jupyter_client                7.3.5
jupyter-core                  4.10.0
jupyterlab-pygments           0.2.2
keras                         2.8.0
Keras-Preprocessing           1.1.2
keyring                       23.5.0
kiwisolver                    1.4.2
lazy-object-proxy             1.7.1
libclang                      14.0.1
llvmlite                      0.38.1
Markdown                      3.3.6
MarkupSafe                    2.1.1
matplotlib                    3.5.1
matplotlib-inline             0.1.3
mccabe                        0.6.1
mistune                       0.8.4
mypy-extensions               0.4.3
nbclient                      0.6.0
nbconvert                     6.5.0
nbformat                      5.3.0
nest-asyncio                  1.5.5
numba                         0.55.2
numpy                         1.21.6
numpydoc                      1.2.1
oauthlib                      3.2.0
opt-einsum                    3.3.0
packaging                     21.3
pandas                        1.4.3
pandocfilters                 1.5.0
parso                         0.8.3
pathspec                      0.9.0
patsy                         0.5.2
pexpect                       4.8.0
pickleshare                   0.7.5
Pillow                        9.1.0
pip                           22.2.2
platformdirs                  2.5.2
pluggy                        1.0.0
poyo                          0.5.0
prompt-toolkit                3.0.29
protobuf                      3.20.1
psutil                        5.9.0
ptyprocess                    0.7.0
pure-eval                     0.2.2
pyasn1                        0.4.8
pyasn1-modules                0.2.8
pycodestyle                   2.8.0
pycparser                     2.21
pydocstyle                    6.1.1
pyflakes                      2.4.0
Pygments                      2.12.0
pylint                        2.13.7
pyls-spyder                   0.4.0
PyOpenGL                      3.1.6
pyparsing                     3.0.8
PyQt5                         5.12.3
PyQt5-Qt5                     5.15.2
PyQt5-sip                     12.10.1
PyQtWebEngine                 5.12.1
PyQtWebEngine-Qt5             5.15.2
pyrsistent                    0.18.1
python-dateutil               2.8.2
python-lsp-black              1.2.1
python-lsp-jsonrpc            1.0.0
python-lsp-server             1.5.0
python-slugify                6.1.2
pytz                          2022.1
pyxdg                         0.27
pyzmq                         24.0.1
QDarkStyle                    3.0.3
qstylizer                     0.2.1
QtAwesome                     1.1.1
qtconsole                     5.3.2
QtPy                          2.1.0
requests                      2.27.1
requests-oauthlib             1.3.1
rope                          1.0.0
rsa                           4.8
Rtree                         1.0.0
scikeras                      0.9.0
scikit-learn                  1.0.2
scipy                         1.8.0
seaborn                       0.11.2
SecretStorage                 3.3.2
setuptools                    50.3.2
six                           1.16.0
sklearn                       0.0
sktime                        0.12.0
snowballstemmer               2.2.0
sortedcontainers              2.4.0
soupsieve                     2.3.2.post1
Sphinx                        4.5.0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp       1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp         1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp        2.0.0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath          1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp          1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5
spyder                        5.3.3
spyder-kernels                2.3.3
statsmodels                   0.13.2
stopit                        1.1.2
tensorboard                   2.8.0
tensorboard-data-server       0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit        1.8.1
tensorflow                    2.8.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.25.0
termcolor                     1.1.0
text-unidecode                1.3
textdistance                  4.2.2
tf-estimator-nightly          2.8.0.dev2021122109
threadpoolctl                 3.1.0
three-merge                   0.1.1
tinycss2                      1.1.1
toml                          0.10.2
tomli                         2.0.1
torch                         1.11.0
torchaudio                    0.11.0
torchvision                   0.12.0
tornado                       6.2
TPOT                          0.11.7
tqdm                          4.64.0
traitlets                     5.1.1
typing_extensions             4.2.0
ujson                         5.2.0
update-checker                0.18.0
urllib3                       1.26.9
varname                       0.8.3
watchdog                      2.1.9
wcwidth                       0.2.5
webencodings                  0.5.1
Werkzeug                      2.1.2
whatthepatch                  1.0.2
wheel                         0.37.1
wrapt                         1.14.0
wurlitzer                     3.0.2
xgboost                       1.6.0
yapf                          0.32.0
zipp                          3.8.0
```

This is on a shared machine, is it possible that someone could have changed something to cause the error? Does anyone have a fix?

Comment: can you do `which python3` and see where is the location of your python3? your spider IDE is using the python located in `lib64/python3.9`. You need to check if your packages are installed for the same interpreter. It might be that your spider IDE is using a virtual environment

Comment: From my spyder env: `which python3
~/spyder-env/bin/python3
`  Outside of it : `/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: yup, spyder points to `spyder-env/bin/python3`. You should either install the packages to this environment or point spyder to use your python in `lib64/python3.9` Take a look at https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment

Comment: The packages are all installed in my spyder-env

Comment: `(spyder-env) [<machineName> ~]$ python3 -m pip list
Package       Version
----------------------------- -------------------
pyparsing                     3.0.8
PyQt5             5.12.3
PyQt5-Qt5        5.15.2
PyQt5-sip       12.10.1
PyQtWebEngine                 5.12.1
PyQtWebEngine-Qt5             5.15.2
spyder           5.3.3
spyder-kernels      2.3.3
`

Answer (score -1):

Unsetting the library path seemed to resolve the issue. Something local on the machine was going wrong.

```
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```